# Android - Parcel a Span object

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

My goal is to serialize spanned objects only, without text.

I was very happy to found that all(most of them) `Span` objects implement `Parcelable` interface

But it turned out that Android doesn't follow the Parcelable protocol and there is no `CREATOR` object in their implementations :
*`ParcelableSpan` - A special kind of `Parcelable` for objects that will serve as text spans*

Does anyone know the way to serialize `Span` objects (for example `StyleSpan`) ?

Comment: see `android.text.TextUtils` docs

Comment: HI @pskink, I guess you a referring https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#writeToParcel(java.lang.CharSequence, android.os.Parcel, int) But this thing parcels the whole Text with styles and I wanted only the styles which are not CharSequence

Comment: no i am referring the `Creator<CharSequence>`

Comment: ok, how do I use this, please ? there is no description

Comment: see `Parcelable.Creator` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html), here you have its implementation: http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java#678

Comment: thanks a lot @pskink I think I can adopt the implementation to skip the actual string from persisting

Comment: but the spans cannot flow in the air - they have to be attached to some string

Comment: I see, I want to pass them between processes and attach them to a string. Hope it's possible

Comment: so attach them to an empty string and if its not possible (i saw somewhere that 0 length spans are forbidden) then attach to "_" or something

Comment: Can I know what's the purpose of that?